# AWS ElasticBeanstalk for PHP is stripping the first slash off some requests

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, amazon-web-services

I've noticed that the leading slash gets stripped from requests and subsequently alters `REQUEST_URI` based routing lookups in my application. Is there either a way to disable this or documentation on how it works so I can make my app aware/adapt the `REQUEST_URI` accordingly?

Example:

`//boo` becomes `/boo`

`///` becomes `//`

`/~///` remains `/~///`

Ideally, `//boo` would remain `//boo` as distinct from `/boo`.